# Does Android VideoView cache streamed videos?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

It looks like VideoView/Mediaplayer have no automatic caching. Is it just me?
Does Android VideoView cache streamed videos? Or does it download it again for every playback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no cache. You can insert a proxy server into the mix and cache it yourself if you need it.

Comment: Right. That is [AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) does.